# Bone shapes can generate issues in exporting process?

Tags: rigging

I would like to know if bone shapes can generate several problems for exporting model, I am finishin my rigging process, I have the bones in my 3D model , but before to animate it and export it at the future I must create bone shapes to get better view in the viewport to animate my 3D character, If I will finish my model animation and decided to export it as "fbx" file , bones shapes can be export it? I prefer to not ! however there are several options for export "mesh,armature, light,empties,etc" I prefer to not export bone shapes, how can avoid that?

pd : shapes bones just change the shapes right? do not affect the bone, just the shape?

Comment: why don't you just try exporting as FBX then imports it back and see what happens?

Comment: I asume I need to check "mesh and animation" how ever I trhink this shapes bones are simply for the viewport, to get confortable animation aspects in time reducing.

Comment: Have you tried it? You already have the armature and bone shapes,...try exporting then importing then see what happens and tell us the updates.

Comment: ok not see in unity.

Comment: That's good as this is what you wanted, right? :)

Comment: yes thx, to you

Comment: You are welcome. It will be good to write what you found out as an answer to your question so it will be helpful for other people